# How can I find users when they return from a remote site I redirected them to?

Tags: php, security, redirect, credit-card, billing

I'm working on an e-commerce site,

In some countries, the credit company asks you to redirect the user to a certain page in an external website (which the credit company gave permission to bill on-line). That site bills the user, and redirects them back to the main site.

The main question is: what is the best way to ensure that the user returns and get recognized correctly so I can attach the basket and data.

I was thinking of:

- `$_session`
- `$_post`
- and a login system of course.

the remote returns the user to dynamic address with a key that's generated and passed to me before the user get redirected.

Comment: Use that KEY you just mentioned.

Comment: No offense, but I really don't understand that you are working on an application that handles people's money and other private data and have to ask such basic info. Can't you start on a more innocent application?

Comment: @CodeCaster oh, if only I could vote you up more times. :-(

Comment: no offense taken, but i need to start from some where, I've  programmed several website, but this is the first website requiring a security issue.
and i was thinking this is the place to ask this questions, maybe i was wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks exactly the same as how Paypal, Facebook, and others perform this function. You have two components to this

1. You need to have something on your site to identify the user. You can keep in session or specify values in the "return url" if you can.
2. You need to get some sort of token from the external company that they user actually paid. Otherwise, there's nothing stopping the user from simply entering the url. Sounds like the KEY you get back is exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (also the negative ones).
i was wondering what is the most SECURE way.

is SESSION safe inaf, or should i use a SQL data pulled by the REGISTERED user.